# Groovy withBatch without need for closure

Tags: groovy

I am making use of withBatch API as:

```
int[] modifyCount = sql.withBatch(batchSize, updateQuery) { ps ->
        keyValue.each { k,v ->
            ps.addBatch(keyvalue:k, newvalue:v)
        }
    }
```

In closure, I set values for the placeholders in the updateQuery. It works fine.

Suppose updateQuery has already all the fields defined and hence code inside closure above is not actually needed now.

What change is needed for that?

Answer (score 0):

there is no reason to use `withBatch` if `updateQuery` contains all values.

just use

```
sql.execute( updateQuery )
```

doc: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html#execute(java.lang.String)